# JavaScript calculates my economic growth

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script and a div with "counter" id:

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("January 1, 2017 00:00:00"); // data de start
var INTERVAL = 1;  // in secunde
var INCREMENT = 1400.53; // crestere per secunda
var START_VALUE = 1400.53; // valoare initiala
var count = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
  var now = new Date();
  count = parseInt(((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE);
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
  setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = parseInt(count);", msInterval);

};
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

This script calculates my economic growth per second from the beginning of 2017 after a certain amount.

So my problem is: I have 5 different START_VALUE number so I need to export 5 counters in 5 divs. How can I use the same code but not to duplicate the whole script? What I need to change is only `var START_VALUE` and `var INCREMENT`!?

Comment: Create a function with parameters `(var id, var START_VALUE, var INCREMENT)`

Comment: Yes, but how to implement that function on that script? I don't have enough knowledge to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are great resources for learning basic Javascript. A simple Google search will direct you to something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_functions.htm).

The easiest way to reuse code is by creating a function. Functions take arguments that change the output based on what you input. You can think of it kind of like `f(x) = x^2` in mathematics, where `x` is the input and you get some output `y`.

In your case, the function would look something like this:

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("January 1, 2017 00:00:00"); // data de start
var INTERVAL = 1;  // in secunde
var count = 0;

function countFunc(id, start_value, increment) {
  var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
  var now = new Date();
  count = parseInt(((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * increment + start_value);
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = count;
  setInterval("count += " + increment + "; document.getElementById('" + id + "').innerHTML = parseInt(count);", msInterval);
}

countFunc("counter1", 1000, 1000);
countFunc("counter2", 1400, 1400);
countFunc("counter3", 1500, 1500);
countFunc("counter4", 1600, 1600);
countFunc("counter5", 1000, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="counter1"></div>
<div id="counter2"></div>
<div id="counter3"></div>
<div id="counter4"></div>
<div id="counter5"></div>
```

Notice how I hardly changed your code, except for the things that needed to change. You were on the right track. The start value and the increment need to change. In this case, the id also needs to change for every div.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But as you can see on this screenshot, all counters return the same value: http://prntscr.com/h5stoj

Comment: @AdelinCraita Those numbers are not all the same. Look at the 8th, 9th, and 10th digits.

Comment: @ Yes I saw but the code not work in properly. We are in November so if you implement the first counter with 1400.53 the result should be start with 37 ... etc. You can saw that if you click for 2-3 times on run code snippet!

Comment: @AdelinCraita I wasn't concerned with the specific implementation of your program when I gave my answer. Try moving your definitions of `START_DATE` and `INTERVAL` and `count` into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try work with JSON:

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("January 1, 2017 00:00:00"); // data de start
var INTERVAL = 1;  // in secunde
var FULL_DATA = [
    {START_VALUE: 1400.53, INCREMENT: 1400.53, count: 0 },
    {START_VALUE: 1401.53, INCREMENT: 1401.53, count: 0 },
    {START_VALUE: 1402.53, INCREMENT: 1402.53, count: 0 },
    {START_VALUE: 1403.53, INCREMENT: 1403.53, count: 0 },
    {START_VALUE: 1404.53, INCREMENT: 1404.53, count: 0 }
]
var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
var now = new Date();
function inc(){
    for(var i in FULL_DATA){
           var data = FULL_DATA[i];
        if (data.count == 0){
         data.count = parseInt(((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * data.INCREMENT + data.START_VALUE);
       }else{
       data.count += data.INCREMENT;
           }
        document.getElementById('counter' + i).innerHTML = parseInt(data.count);
    }
}
setInterval(inc, msInterval);
```

```html
<div id="counter0"></div>
<div id="counter1"></div>
<div id="counter2"></div>
<div id="counter3"></div>
<div id="counter4"></div>
```